# Two MobilePush apps connected to the same mobile app

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

What are the impacts of connecting the same mobile app to two different MobilePush apps on Marketing Cloud?

The same contact can log in to different accounts through the mobile app, and hence the context changes every time.

Is it recommended to use one app only on Marketing Cloud given the fact that there is only one mobile app? If yes, what happens if the contact is pushed to SFMC multiples times depending on the context?

PS: the device ID will remain the same for the contact and will be used by him only.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to maintain a consumer within 2 BUs simultaneously is an unsupported use-case and should not be done.